# What specification of a workstation shall I look for to be used for Machine learning and Reconstruction?

Tags: graphics-cards, high-end

I have to purchase a workstation at office. I have very little knowledge about hardware and what config (GPU, Memory, Processor) should I take so that it has enough hardware to work with state of the art things such as CNN, good graphics and visualization softwares and development, high end image processing tools and development such as reconstructions. 
Budget is around 15k to 17k USD. Budget is for hardware only

I will be using mostly open source libraries for Machine learning and Image processing. I am looking out for a workstation which should do good working with 1000s of images of each size 10 MB and resolution max could be 2k by 2k.

Or in otherway can you please suggest a good workstation which will run Libraries and platforms like tensorflow, Keras etc. for pattern recognition and also for practicing and developing Computed Tomography Reconstruction algorithms.

Comment: *PC which will run Libraries and platforms like tensorflow, Keras etc*  Is there a PC that *won't* run these things?

Comment: @Digital I mean effectively.

Comment: **Don't** just re-ask your question because it was closed. You were receiving help to edit your question to an acceptable point in the comments there.